# How do I dynamically inflate a protobuf object in python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm accessing a web service that provides 1) a protobuf schema and 2) binary data of a given protobuf message. The protobuf schema is retrieved in ZIP format, and contains a .proto file that is defined roughly as:

```
message FooMessage {
  //stuff
  ... 
}

//other .proto fun...
```

Once I've fetched the .proto file, I compile it:

```
protoc --python_out=. path/to/message
```

And then I import the module:

```
module = importlib.import_module(libName, package=pkg)
```

The next step is to go and fetch the binary data for the given object. I do that and store it as a `data = io.BytesIO` object.

So now I want to inflate the FooMessage object with my fetched binary data that is defined in the .proto file, ala:

```
obj = module.FooMessage(data)
```

Questions:

1. How can I retrieve the `FooMessage` class name from the `module`
   that I've imported so that I can build the objects dynamically?
2. Even if I "cheat" and look at the compiled code for a single .proto file, I don't see an obvious way to pass in the binary data to inflate the `FooMessage_pb2.py` object. There doesn't seem to be a method that would take in the binary data to instantiate the object ala: `obj = module.FooMessage(data)`

Clearly I'm doing / thinking about this in the wrong way. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You have the schema, you have the data, that conforms these schema. What's the problem?

Comment: I fetch a .proto file that I compile into a _pb2.py class.

Comment: ignore that comment. I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, they include the class name in the schema. I just missed it.

Well, for #2, I just need to use the `module.FooMessage.FromString(data)` method which was not immediately obvious in the documentation.